# User input from text box and radio buttons reiterated in an alert, showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, alert

Basically what I'm attempting to do is a mad lib story with user input. I've gotten to the stage where I need to show an alert with each input, alert("hello "+name+". You've chosen "+userinput+", etc)

My alert is showing up, but the information is not collecting from the textboxes/radio buttons. It is simply showing undefined.

This is what I have so far..

The purpose of this step is to add the code to the new function so that it will create our story.
Add JavaScript statements to your function to collect all the information from each form element.
Display the user’s information in one alert function.
For Example: ”Hello [name], your story values are [title], [vegetable], [adjective], [number #1], [number #2]”

```
function beginstory() {

alert("welcome "+name+". you have chosen: "+title+" "+hobby+" "+adjective+" "+number1+" ");
                var name=(document.getElementById('username').value);
                var title = document.getElementById("storytitle").value;
                var hobby = document.getElementById("hobby").value;
                var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
                var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
                var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
                var trex = document.getElementById("trex").value;
                var steg = document.getElementById("steg").value;
                var diplod = document.getElementById("diplod").value;
                var crazy = document.getElementById("crazy").value;
                var charming = document.getElementById("charming").value;
                var curious = document.getElementById("curious").value;
                var he = document.getElementById("he").value;
                var she = document.getElementById("she").value;
                var ze = document.getElementById("ze").value;
                var jurassic = document.getElementById("jurassic").value;
                var colonial = document.getElementById("colonial").value;
                var twenty = document.getElementById("twenty").value;}
```

```
     <form id="story" action="">

            What is your name?                  <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="username"><br>
            What is the title of your story?    <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="storytitle"><br>
            Name a hobby:                       <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="hobby"><br>
            Name an adjective trait:            <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="adjective"><br>
            Name a number greater than one:     <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="number1"><br>
            Name another number greater than one: <input type="text" name="storyelements" id="number2"><br>

            Choose a dinosaur:                  <input type="radio" name="dinosaur" id="trex" checked="checked">Tyrannosaurus Rex
                                                <input type="radio" name="dinosaur" id="steg">Stegosaurus
                                                <input type="radio" name="dinosaur" id="diplod">Diplodocus<br>

            Choose a personality trait:         <input type="radio" name="trait" id="crazy" checked="checked">Crazy
                                                <input type="radio" name="trait" id="charming">Charming
                                                <input type="radio" name="trait" id="curious">Curious<br>

            Choose your preferred pronoun:      <input type="radio" name="pronoun" id="he" checked="checked">He
                                                <input type="radio" name="pronoun" id="she">She
                                                <input type="radio" name="pronoun" id="ze">Ze<br>

            Choose an era:                      <input type="radio" name="era" id="jurassic" checked="checked">Jurassic
                                                <input type="radio" name="era" id="colonial">Colonial
                                                <input type="radio" name="era" id="twenty">The 1920s<br>
            <!-- BUTTONS -->
                                        <input type="button" onclick="beginstory()" name="storytime" value="Start Your Story!"></button><br>
                                        <input type="reset" name="clearform" value="Clear Form">


  </form>
```

Comment: My apologies for not inputting my attempts. I will be sure to read the guidelines more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might try defining the variables BEFORE you display them.

As is, you are trying this:

```
alert("welcome "+name+". you have chosen: "+title+" "+hobby+" "+adjective+" "+number1+" ");
var name=(document.getElementById('username').value);
var title = document.getElementById("storytitle").value;
...
```

See how you are telling it to display, for example, 'name'... and then in the very next line telling it what name should mean?

Try flipping that around.

```
...
var colonial = document.getElementById("colonial").value;
var twenty = document.getElementById("twenty").value;}
alert("welcome "+name+". you have chosen: "+title+" "+hobby+" "+adjective+" "+number1+" ");
```

By putting the alert at the end of the function instead of the beginning, you have defined the variables, and THEN told it where to display them.

Should work better for ya.

** EXPANDED **

OK... to grab the buttons that get selected:

All form elements will have a name or an id.  These are used to pass information to the server in name=value pairs whenever the form is submitted.

Most people prefer id for most things, but on radio buttons specifically, you should have a name set; this allows you to have two or more buttons return their value under the same identifier:

```
<label>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"></label>
<label>Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></label>
```

That doesn't work with id's because id's need to be unique.

You can then create a variable and load it with the radio button itself:

```
var myButton = document.getElementByName('gender');
```

This returns **BOTH** radio buttons, because they both have the same name.  It return them in an array, and to access them, you simply use array notation:

```
var maleButton = myButton[0];  // These are stored in the order they are found in 
var femaleButton = myButton[1];// in the HTML
```

*NOTE: document.getElementById('youridhere') returns a single value instead of an array, since id's are always unique... but we can't use it here, since these are not using id's.*

You can then access the members of these objects just like you would any other:

```
alert("The value of maleButton is " + maleButton.value);
```

Should alert "male".

If that was the only data you needed out of the object, you could have grabbed that originally, however, and saved some typing:

```
var myValue = document.getElementByName('gender')[0].value;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh my goodness, I feel silly.
I had it that way originally, but my alert() stopped working and I fiddled with things too much in a completely illogical way.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I've got another question... How can I access which radio buttons the user has selected to throw into the alert()?
I'm thinking I need to use an if statement, but I just can't figure out where.

Comment: That depends on what you are going to do with the information... do you just need the name of the button, or do you actually need to play with the button itself?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

I need to play with the buttons themselves. The point of the exercise is to get an alert stating all of the variables input by the user, including each .checked radio button. This is my first time playing around with JS; I'm finding it waaaay more difficult than I anticipated!

Comment: It isn't that hard, really, ONCE you get use to how it sees objects and such; it really isn't like other C based languages at all [recommend 'Javascript - The Good Parts'].

Comment: @user2624540 Also answered your question more directly in an edit of the original answer.